# Access to exchanges' (especially Mt. Gox's) transaction history?

Tags: transactions, mtgox, raw-data

I'm attempting to do statistical research on the Bitcoin market, and I would like to have access to the transaction data of as many exchanges as possible. Specifically, I'm looking for every trade made on a given exchange. Mt. Gox is obviously my primary interest because it handles the highest volume. Is this data available for download anywhere, or am I going to have to start collecting it myself? Specifically, I want to be able to store all transactions in a SQL database, so I would like them in an easily parsable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API) to retrieve such data.

Comment: Ah, right, specifically [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Multi_currency_trades). Thanks @Lohoris.

Answer (score 0):

I found a SQL database of all Mt. Gox transactions (updated every few hours) along with the accompanying Python scripts [here](http://cahier2.ww7.be/bitcoinmirror/phantomcircuit/).